# Delegation between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

i know how to set up a "normal" delegation between to ViewController, which are directly dependent. So if i say, i have to send a message from one view to its upper one, i know how to do this.
But how do i set up a delegate, if there are more ViewControllers between the two?

So m let's say i have this setup according to the scheme:

ViewController1   ->   ViewController2   ->   ViewController3
          (via ButtonPressed)     (via ButtonPressed)

If i want to set a (for example) NSString in VC1 from VC2, i just write into the prepareForSegue, where i call the VC2:

```
VC2.delegate = self;
```

But what do i do when i want to transfer Data between VC3 and VC1 without having to change VC2?
What do i set the delegate for, if it isn't "self"? 
I know my description is very bad, but i cannot describe it better.

I just want this: VC1 has one button and a label; the button opens VC2, which has one button too, but no label; this VC2Button shows VC3; And with a touch to the button in the VC3 i want to change the label in VC1. But without having to set a delegte to VC2 and then another to VC1, i know how this works.

Hope you get what i want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check other sources of communication like NSNotification or KVO.

Comment: Thanks! The NSNotification solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) may help if you don't want to maintain too many pointers just to link two unrelated views together.

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass on the delegate from VC2 to VC3 like this:

```
Inside VC1:
VC2 *vc2 = [VC2 alloc] init];
vc2.delegate = self;

Inside VC2:
VC3 *vc3 = [VC3 alloc] init];
vc3.delegate = self.delegate;
```

Or you can use target-selector design pattern to achieve this.

**Target-Selector way:**

```
Inside VC1:
VC2 *vc2 = [VC2 alloc] initWithTarget:(id)iTarget andSelector:(SEL)iSelector];

Inside VC2: Pass on the target/selector received from VC1
VC3 *vc3 = [VC3 alloc] initWithTarget:(id)iTarget andSelector:(SEL)iSelector];
```

Comment: But then i have to import the header and the protocol from VC3 in every ViewController right? So also in VC2.
How does target-selector design pattern work?

Comment: ok sorry but i don't understand it. What is the big difference between the to ways? it seems to me they have the same effort..

Comment: don't get me wrong, but i search a way to eliminate the coding in the middle VC. So i don't have to import headers and delegates or something..

Comment: The protocol that is being used by the delegate can be defined in a .h file so that you don't need to expose the view controller header files to each other and instead you just include the protocol .h file in those files who use it.